# What does CFL only mean when describing a VGA port?

Tags: vga, desktop-computer

Looking at the configuration of a [Dell Inspiron 3470 Mini Desktop](https://www.dell.com/en-uk/shop/desktops-all-in-ones/inspiron-3470-desktop/spd/inspiron-3470-desktop?~ck=bt) it lists

> 1 x VGA (CFL only)

in the list of ports.

What does CFL only mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that this refers to [Coffee Lake (CFL)](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/microarchitectures/coffee_lake) CPUs. This would be [Intel 8th Generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee_Lake) processors.

It is possible that amongst the options for the machines are Kaby Lake (KBL) or other processors that do not support VGA output.

CFL in technology would normally refer to Compact Fluorescent Tube, typically used as a backlight for LCD screens, but this is completely irrelevant to VGA as VGA does not care at all and has no concept of driving a backlight.  Instead it would make more sense that certain CPUs dropped support for VGA because it requires digital to analogue converters (DACs) which would be extra electronics that could be left off to save money and space.

Comment: Interesting though I wonder why they didn't just put some more obvious like "Intel 8th generation only".

Comment: I do agree that "(CFL only)" is an odd choice. Most people would know them as "8th Generation" rather than Coffee Lake, let alone a slightly odd contraction of the product family code name likely only found in Intel designer documentation. I don't see any other reasonable explanation for what CFL would be nor what else might mean that VGA output ability depends on it. I suspect that it was copied from an internal design document at Dell and because the marketing people had no idea what CFL was they just copied it verbatim and let the end user figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm showing my age, but perhaps this VGA (CFL only) pertains to the type of VGA monitor that may be used.  VGA graphics have been in use since the 1980's, at least.  In that time the only type of monitors in general usage were CRT based (Cathode Ray Tube), much like the standard TV's of that time, and these used VGA graphics adapters.

My thought is that this description is used to indicate that the monitor must use CFL technology, which would limit the usage to only LCD type monitors and exclude usage of CRT monitors.  Why anyone today might use a CRT monitor is questionable, as they at very least take up so much more desk space, unlike flat screen LCD's. But then there are some who would 'pay with desk space', rather than purchase a new monitor.